Separate a list into smaller lists based on column names
I have a list like this:
df_list <- list(
  df1 = data.frame(A = 1:3, B = 4:6),
  df2 = data.frame(A = 7:9, B = 10:12),
  df3 = data.frame(A = 13:15, C = 16:18),
  df4 = data.frame(A = 19:21, B = 22:24, C = 25:27)
)

For all data frames in this list that have the same number of columns AND the same column names, I want to put them into a separate list (e.g. list_1, list_2, list_3...).
Does anyone know if there is a quick way to do this?

split(df_list, sapply(df_list, \(x) paste(sort(make.names(names(x))), collapse = " ")))

What is your desired output for this toy data?

@ Ric: I think this is the way to write it in the old version of R? split(df_list, sapply(df_list, function(x) paste(sort(make.names(names(x))), collapse = " ")))

Create a function to do this.
split_list <- function(lst) {
  res <- lapply(unique(lapply(lst, names)), \(x) {
    lapply(lst, \(y) y[identical(names(y), x)]) })
  
  for(i in 1:length(res)) {
    assign(paste("list", i, sep="_"), res[[i]]
           [sapply(res[[i]], \(x) ncol(x)>0)], .GlobalEnv)
  }
}

Then call this function to create the separate lists in the environment.
split_list(df_list)

list_1
$df1
  A B
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6

$df2
  A  B
1 7 10
2 8 11
3 9 12

list_2
$df3
   A  C
1 13 16
2 14 17
3 15 18

list_3
$df4
   A  B  C
1 19 22 25
2 20 23 26
3 21 24 27


@ Edward: I think this is how you would do this in the old version of R?

split_list <- function(lst) {
unique_names <- unique(lapply(lst, names))
res <- lapply(unique_names, function(x) {
lapply(lst, function(y) {
if (identical(names(y), x)) y else NULL
})
})

for(i in seq_along(res)) {
current_list <- res[[i]]
non_empty_list <- Filter(function(x) !is.null(x) && ncol(x) > 0, current_list)
assign(paste("list", i, sep="_"), non_empty_list, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
}

Yes. Looks better your way.
